# R: data frame reorganization throws "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0" error

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns. One of the columns is a string of aggregated IDs and I need to break out each ID and give it its own row. I can do this for each row individually as seen here:

```
    > UPI.download[1:20,]
            Design.ID                                                                  Glados.SKU
5  KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
6  KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
7  KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1                                                                            
8  KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
9  KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
10 KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1                                                                            
11 KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
12 KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
13 KBAMI7-00VU-INSGN1                                                                            
14 KCLRI7-0FLA-WAVE01                                                                            
15 K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1                                                          K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1
16 K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1                                                          K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1
17 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1;KCLRI7-0GON-INSGN1;KCLR7X-0GON-INSGN1;KCLR6X-0GON-INSGN1
18 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1                                                                            
19 KBAMI7-0GSU-INSGN1                                                                            
20 KCLRI7-0GSU-INSGN1 KCLR7X-0GSU-INSGN1;KCLR6X-0GSU-INSGN1;KCLRI7-0GSU-INSGN1;KCLRI6-0GSU-INSGN1
21 KUSB08-0TAM-BRICK1                                                          KUSB08-0TAM-BRICK1
22 K510WD-0LSU-PASLY1                                                          K510WD-0LSU-PASLY1
23 KCLR8P-0MST-INSGN1                                                          KCLR8P-0MST-INSGN1
24 KCLRI6-0TCU-INSGN1 KCLR6X-0TCU-INSGN1;KCLRI6-0TCU-INSGN1;KCLR7X-0TCU-INSGN1;KCLRI7-0TCU-INSGN1
> y = strsplit(UPI.download[13,2],";")
> z = data.frame(UPI.download[13,1],y)
> colnames(z) = c("Design.ID","Glados.SKU")
> z
           Design.ID         Glados.SKU
1 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1
2 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLRI7-0GON-INSGN1
3 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLR7X-0GON-INSGN1
4 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLR6X-0GON-INSGN1
```

But when I try and create a loop I get the following:

```
    > for(i in nrow(UPI.download)){
+   UPIs = strsplit(UPI.download[i,2],";")
+   new.frame = data.frame(UPI.download[i,1],UPIs)
+ }
Error in data.frame(UPI.download[i, 1], UPIs) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

[image: Console Image of the script and error]

Either I am way off or there is just a minor tweak that I am not understanding

Comment: What happens when you run `strsplit('', ';')`?

Comment: Do you mean if I use single quotes rather than double quotes? it seems to be fine as long as I reference the cell of the UPI.download data frame properly.

Comment: No, the point is that it returns `character(0)` which has `length` 0, i.e. why the error message tells you there are differing number of rows.

Comment: Also, just FYI your loop only deals with the last row of `UPI.download`. You need to change it to `i in 1:nrow(UPI.download)`.

Comment: Ok, but I do want the second column to be blank if there is no matching data in the 'Glados.SKU' column. Is there a way to make R ok with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data is in a `data.frame` called `dat`. There were a few issues with your original code: first (as @Yannis mentioned) you were not properly iterating, so you needed to write `1:nrow(dat)` instead of `nrow(dat)`. Next, the informative error message said there was a mismatch of row length. This was caused by a result of `character(0)` from `strsplit`-ing a blank value. We need to check the `length` of the `unlist`ed `strsplit` result. This is captured in the `if` statement in our `for` loop. Finally, we `rbind` the results together. Note that this `for` loop will be rather inefficient on larger data sets. In general, I wouldn't advise iterating in this style, but it got the job done.

```
# initialize big data frame
big.frame <- data.frame(
  'Design.ID' = character(0),
  'Glados.SKU' = character(0),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# for each row
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
     # split the string and unlist the result
     UPIs = unlist(strsplit(dat[i,2],";"))
     if(length(UPIs) == 0){ # if it's blank, just make column blank
       new.frame = data.frame('Design.ID' = dat[i,1],
                              'Glados.SKU' = '',
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     }else{ #otherwise insert the vector
       new.frame = data.frame('Design.ID' = dat[i,1],
                              'Glados.SKU' = UPIs,
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     }
     # rbind to bigger frame
     big.frame <- rbind.data.frame(big.frame,
                                   new.frame,
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

            Design.ID         Glados.SKU
1  KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1                   
2  KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1                   
3  KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1                   
4  KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1                   
5  KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1                   
6  KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1                   
7  KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1                   
8  KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1                   
9  KBAMI7-00VU-INSGN1                   
10 KCLRI7-0FLA-WAVE01                   
11 K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1 K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1
12 K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1 K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1
13 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1
14 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLRI7-0GON-INSGN1
15 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLR7X-0GON-INSGN1
16 KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1 KCLR6X-0GON-INSGN1
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(Design.ID = c("KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1", "KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1", 
                                    "KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1", "KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1", "KUWB08-00VU-INSGN1", 
                                    "KGLGI7-00VU-FETTI1", "KPBK4K-00VU-INSGN1", "KCLRI7-00VU-INSGN1", 
                                    "KBAMI7-00VU-INSGN1", "KCLRI7-0FLA-WAVE01", "K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1", 
                                    "K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1", "KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1"), 
                      Glados.SKU = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "K510WL-0WEB-PRIME1", "K110MS-0WEB-PRIME1", 
                                     "KCLRI6-0GON-INSGN1;KCLRI7-0GON-INSGN1;KCLR7X-0GON-INSGN1;KCLR6X-0GON-INSGN1"
                                    )), 
                 .Names = c("Design.ID", "Glados.SKU"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```